# 'this' in chartJS in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

This is my chartJS onclick event handler in angular:

```
legend: {
          onClick: this.toggleLegendClickHandler
```

From that method I need to update a chart after y scale title text is changed. I would like to do this like `this._chart.chart.update()` where `_chart` is childview angular directive.

However, `this` is not a component object but `Legend` object which received an event. Can I have `this` in that handler as angular component object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow function to define `toggleLegendClickHandler` function It will point to component object

```
export class ChartComponent{
    
    legend: {onClick: this.toggleLegendClickHandler}
    
    toggleLegendClickHandler = ()=>{
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Was confused wiht `this` in JS, now I learned something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` shadow,
suppose this is your code,

```
chartFunction() {
     const _that = this;  // creating shadow of this

    createChart({
    data: {
            legend: {
              onClick: _that.toggleLegendClickHandler
            }
    }
    });

}
```

now it will refer the component class reference.